# mostrar texto emergente

Tags: html, css

Tengo el menu de incio ya hecho pero tengo que mostrar un texto emergente y no se por donde empezar..

debería de quedar así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado el abbr, pero no me sirve ya que no quiero que muestre os puntos de abajo, que otras formas puedo conseguir?

saludos!

Comment: Échale un vistazo al concepto de ToolTip en HTML y CSS en [este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp)

Answer (score 1):

A lo que tu te refieres es como crear un tooltip supongo, te dejo el siguente ejemplo de w3schools

[Ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_bottom)

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<li class="tooltip">
  INICIO
  <span class="tooltiptext">Texto a mostrar al pasar el mouse</span>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el problema que tengo es que el tooltip tiene que ser de un <li> no de un button...

Comment: Pues nada mas seria cambiar las etiquetas las clases css se respetan